# Could not install Applications Manager (ArcGIS Server 10)

Tags: arcgis-server, installation

I try to install ArcGIS Server version 10.
Everything worked fine with installing the GIS Services.
The Server is running. I can create services and see them in ArcCatalog.
But when I try to install the Web Applications I couldn't select the "Applications Manager".

I try to install it on Windows Server 2008 (64bit) with IIS7.
I double checked the settings and [required extensions for IIS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#/Windows_Server_2008_R2_IIS_requirements/00890000000n000000/) and it seems to be correct.
I even changed the IIS seting from 64bit to 32bit.
But the "Application Manager" in the Select Feature Dialog is still not shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may really need to look deeply at your .Net installs, It sounds like you may need to force the aspnet_regiis command reregister the libraries to IIS. I would check your temp folder for the install log file; this usually captures pretty well what dependencies may not be seen.

Answer (score -1):

As the Application manager is based on Visual Studio, I would suggest repairing the Visual Studio on the local machine making sure the Web Dev components are installed and then trying again

This may mean that you may have to change the privileges on the web services folder.

Please let me know how you go,
CDB

Comment: How exactly is the Application Manager based on VS?

Comment: to complete the installation of Application manager you need to have the developement environment you are installing on the machine. As standard if you select .Net it will by default install VS Lite. This is all I was saying

Comment: That seems odd; I don't have any VS tools on my servers and have never had to have them installed there to get the Manager to install.

Comment: There is no VS components for the AGS Server Manager, it is a ASP.Net web-app.